# Pandas dataframe print string + changing variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a program that prompts the user to load a csv file. The csv file always contains the columns StudentID, Name, Assignment1,2,3... **The number of assignments varies**.

I am trying to display a list of names, with one grade for each assignment and the final grade which I calculate from my imported function computeFinalGrade.

***How can I change the last line my code to print the grades and the final grades for the right number of assignments?***

**Desired output:**
if the csv only has "Assignment1", the output should be:

*"Michael Andersen has obtained the grades 10. The final grade is 10"*

if the csv contains 5 assignments, the output should be:

*"Michael Andersen has obtained the grades 10,7,12,7,10. The final grade is 10"*

My code:

```
grades = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=";", skip_header=1)
e = grades[:,2:]
f = computeFinalGrades(e)
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=';')
df['FinalGrade'] = f
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print('{} has obtained the grades {}, {}, {}. The final grade is {}'.format(row['Name'],row['Assignment1'],row['Assignment2'],row['Assignment3'],row['FinalGrade']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=';')
#filter DataFrame by positions
df1 = df.iloc[:,2:]
#count computeFinalGrades
f = computeFinalGrades(df1.values)

#all Assignments convert to joined string
df['Assignment'] = df1.astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1)
df['FinalGrade'] = f

#zip columns together and loop
for name, assign, final in zip(df['Name'],df['Assignment'],df['FinalGrade']):
    #python 3.6+ f-strings
    print(f'{name} has obtained the grades {assign}. The final grade is {final}')
    #python bellow with format
    print('{} has obtained the grades {}. The final grade is {}'.format(name, assign, final))
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name':list('abcd'),
         'StudentID':[7,8,9,4],
         'Assignment1':[1,3,5,7],
         'Assignment2':[5,3,6,9],

})

print (df)
  Name  StudentID  Assignment1  Assignment2
0    a          7            1            5
1    b          8            3            3
2    c          9            5            6
3    d          4            7            9
```

---

```
#sample function
def computeFinalGrades(x):
    return x.sum()

#filter DataFrame by positions
df1 = df.iloc[:,2:]
#count computeFinalGrades
f = computeFinalGrades(df1.values)

#all Assignments convert to joined string
df['Assignment'] = df1.astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1)
df['FinalGrade'] = f
print (df)
  Name  StudentID  Assignment1  Assignment2 Assignment  FinalGrade
0    a          7            1            5       1, 5          39
1    b          8            3            3       3, 3          39
2    c          9            5            6       5, 6          39
3    d          4            7            9       7, 9          39
```

---

```
for name, assign, final in zip(df['Name'],df['Assignment'],df['FinalGrade']):
    print(f'{name} has obtained the grades {assign}. The final grade is {final}')

a has obtained the grades 1, 5. The final grade is 39
b has obtained the grades 3, 3. The final grade is 39
c has obtained the grades 5, 6. The final grade is 39
d has obtained the grades 7, 9. The final grade is 39
```

Comment: How can I display the output by alphabetical order? I have tried to add df.sort('Name', ascending=False) but it returned KeyError: 'Name'

Comment: @bubble33 - You are close, try `sort_values` like `df = df.sort_values('Name', ascending=False) `

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks a lot!